# Accessing variables in PHP files

Tags: php

Is there anyway to access variables of one php file into another?
   - I am trying to validate a form. I need to access variables from the validationConditions.php file in form.php file.

I have tried creating sessions but they are error prone.
I am using the latest version of dreamweaver.
Is it possible to use $_POST to achieve the results?
Any example will be welcome...
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just include the file.

Comment: You can require the file with the variables, use $_POST, or use $_SESSION variables. There is many options.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use session variables. In the first page you could set the values like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar'] = 'My Data';
```

Then in the second page you can retrieve the data like this...

```
session_start();
$myvar = $_SESSION['myvar'];
```

Which in turn sets `$myvar` to `"My Data"`

Answer (score 0):

You can read a php file with another php file. Assume that we have 2 php files.

new.php

```
    <?php
$a="something";
?>
```

serach.php  ---> search in new.php

```
 <?php
// What to look for
$search = '$a'; //WE are searching $a 
$lines = file('new.php'); // in new.php
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false)
    echo $line;

}


?>
```

Something like that. You have to edit this file.

Answer (score 0):

A somehow devious solution:

```
ob_start();

    $request = array(
        "_id"=>"0815",
        "user"=>"john",
        "email"=>"john@dunbar.com",
        "phone"=>NULL
    ); // Don't know. Just how u need your request to look like.

    include('validationConditions.php');

    $response = getValidationConditions($request); // Function in 'validationConditions.php' that responds an array or a JSON

$out = ob_get_clean();

echo json_encode($out);
```